# Unrecognised error when deploying django app to heroku with git push

Tags: django, heroku, command-line-interface, command-prompt, heroku-cli

I have a django app with the following file structure

```
- project_name
        (settings, __init__, urls, asgi, wsgi ... *.py)
- manage.py
- app_name
        - templates
                (template files)
        - static
                (just some static files)
        (urls, views, apps, models __init__ and the other usual files within django app *.py)

- requirements.txt
```

I think that I have run all the necessary commands inside top-level directory (containing project_name and app_name sub-directories)

1. `git init`
2. `heroku git:remote -a (heroku_app_name)`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -am "this is a commit message"`

and then the error comes in `git push heroku master` with the following log:

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting django
remote:          Downloading Django-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
remote:        Collecting django-heroku
remote:          Downloading django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
remote:          Downloading sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.2.10
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz
remote:          Downloading pytz-2020.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2
remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url>=0.5.0
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
remote:        Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
remote:          Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for psycopg2: filename=
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-#############
remote:        Successfully built psycopg2
remote:        Installing collected packages: sqlparse, asgiref, pytz, django, whitenoise, psycopg2, dj-database-url, django-heroku
remote:        Successfully installed asgiref-3.3.1 dj-database-url-0.5.0 django-3.1.3 django-heroku-0.3.1 psycopg2-2.8.6 pytz-2020.4 sqlparse-0.4.1 whitenoise-5.2.0
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 53M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed due to an unrecognized error, and we've been notified.
remote:
remote:  !     Please try pushing again.
remote:  !     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID ###############
remote:
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to (heroku_app_name).
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/(heroku_app_name).git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/(heroku_app_name).git'
```

I decided to disable collecting static with `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1` since it brought more errors but I don't think that it is the issue.

I am running the latest version of Windows 10 Home at the time this question was asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you didn't include the `Procfile` for Heroku deployment. Follow the below guide to create a `Procfile` and setup:

1. Install `gunicorn` library which is a production web server for Django and Flask applications

```
pip install gunicorn
```

2. Add `gunicorn` to your requirements.txt file.

```
pip freeze -r requirements.txt
```

3. Create a new file called `Procfile` in the root of the app. This is your file structure after creating the `Procfile`:

```
- project_name
        (settings, __init__, urls, asgi, wsgi ... *.py)
- manage.py
- app_name
        - templates
                (template files)
        - static
                (just some static files)
        (urls, views, apps, models __init__ and the other usual files within django app *.py)

- requirements.txt
- Procfile
```

4. Add the below line to the `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn projectname.wsgi
```

Note: Replace the "projectname" in `projectname.wsgi` line to your project's name

5. Re-deploy the application

Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration